# Is it possible to have two similar methods (name and parameters) in C# like Ruby?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby

Is C# capable of handling method versions?

For example, if I have two methods with same name and parameters in Ruby, the most recent version gets executed.

How C# handles this? Will it raise an error or execute the recent version?

Comment: Surely this would have been easy enough to test for yourself?

Comment: @AlexanderR Yup, surely but I wanted to know whether anything is possible using something which I am not aware of.

Comment: C# is compiled language so the code will be compiled and if two methods with same name and parameters will lead to ambiguity in your code. In ruby it is interpreted so it won't have a problem to redefine the method again and again.

Comment: @Manar Husrieh: I don't think this has anything to do with the compiled/interpreted distinction. It's simply that the rules of Ruby allow you to do this and the rules of C# don't allow it.

Comment: @LukeH Put yourself in the place of the compiler how can you distinct the two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two methods with the same name and parameter list in the same class in C#. You need to differentiate the methods somehow, either use different names or differing parameter types and/or different number of parameters. You will simply get a compilation error.

While there is no notion of "most recent version" of a method in C#, it sounds like you are trying to accomplish a form of method overriding (I'm not familiar with ruby so I do not know what most recent version means), you may be able to achieve something similar by sub-classing and method overriding.

Answer (score 1):

If they are exactly the same (namespace, class, name, and parameters) you will get compile error.

Answer (score 1):

[Member Overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029.aspx) is a thing of the past in `c#`

The use of `optional parameters` in much better. No duplicate code and less code to maintain.

```
public int SomeCalcMethod(int object1, int object2, int? object3 = null)
{
   return object1 + object2 + (int)(object3 ?? 0);
}
```

No need to have overloaded methods:

```
public int SomeCalcMethod(int object1 , int object2)
{
    return object1 + object2;
}

public int SomeCalcMethod(int object1 , int object2, int object3 )
{
    return object1 + object2+ object3 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have 2 methods with exactly the same signature in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters must be different at least otherwise you will get compile error.

```
class CalculateSomething
{
    public static int Plus(int number1, int number2)
    {
        return Plus(number1, number2, 0);
    }

    public static int Plus(int number1, int number2, int number3)
    {
        return number1 + number2 + number3;
    }
}
```